# Update Next.js URL without the page reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a news page in a Next.js site at the URL `/news`

On the page are some category buttons. Clicking these makes an API request and dynamically changes the posts listed on the page.

What I want is for the URL to reflect these filters, for example `/news/category/entertainment` and `/news/category/technology`

I see 2 options for this, and both have issues.

**Option 1:**

I use Next.js router, for example:

```
router.replace(updatedUrl, undefined, { shallow: true });
```

However, this causes the page to reload every time I change category, which must not happen.

**Option 2:**

I use the history API, for example:

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, updatedUrl);
```

This works almost perfectly, but it breaks the browser back and forward buttons. They correctly take you away to other pages, but if the browser buttons navigate back to the `/news` page then Next.js just does nothing and stays on the previous page. Browser history API is obviously incompatible with Next.js router.

**Question:**

Is there a solution to append my categories to my `/news` URL without Next.js reloading the page, and ensuring the browser back and forwards buttons work? I do not want to use query parameters. I am concluding that it must be impossible, but hoping someone can help.

One of those annoying things that I would know exactly how to do with vanilla js, but I’m stuck fighting a framework that seemingly doesn’t want me to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Wondering if I can use history API and add a history popstate listener, then force Next.js to load the pages that the browser buttons are ignoring. But it seems Next.js already uses this, and I cant see a way to detect whether or not Next.js will handle or ignore history events.

Comment: Maybe use router.push method. 
[link](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router )